# Issue Google Calendar API - Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: api, calendar

I run a gym and have a website on which I run a plugin (TeamBooking) which allows my customers to book their classes online. This plugin uses the Google Calendar API and it's been working great for over a year and a half now.
However, since last Saturday, my customers and I have been receiving the following error code when trying to make a reservation:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I've been looking all around and can't find out why this started happening all of a sudden. The weirdest part is that sometimes, it works for a few moments, and then we get the error code again. It's not consistent.

I have only 1 calendar linked with my Google account. We have a maximum of 8 classes per day, for which we have a maximum of 12 participants, so we don't have more than a 100 reservations per day on average and not more than 12 guests per event, so I'm not over any limit here either.

I've checked my Calendar API and I'm way below my quotas (5,000 requests per day when I can go up to 1M).

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? Any help would be really appreciated as it is a huge problem for me that my clients cannot book their classes.

Comment: This sounds like you would need to contact Google's technical support, in order to why out why it thinks you are over quota.

Comment: Thanks Halfer! Does Google have tech support for free users?

Comment: I don't use Google, but I would expect so. Since they are a very large company, I would imagine their tech support is divided by function, so search on the web for Developer/API Tech Support or Calendar Support. You may have to do it via email.

Comment: Slightly on-topic: whilst I appreciate this does not help you now, you may wish to think long term about how to remove your reliance on free cloud services. When it goes wrong, you don't have a contract to rely upon, but you do have a corporate provider large enough to ignore your difficulty. I hope you can resolve it soon, but I'd regard this as a business risk even once it is fixed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and a month ago we have decided to make the change in the near future. Right now i wish we would have done it sooner. I have posted the message on the google calendar support forum, hopefully someone will answer soon.

Comment: Yes, hope you can get an answer that way. Is there a facility to open a tech support ticket for your specific case? I don't know the forum, but that sounds like a way to have your problem languish unanswered for days. If you are allowed to see other entries on that forum, see if they are getting attention from Google advisers - if so it might be OK.

Comment: Yeah, looks like most people are getting fast replies from experts...but not me.

Comment: Well, I would not expect a reply in an hour, even from a private support ticket directly to their tech support agents - that would be an excellent response time. If all other tickets have got replies then that's a good sign, as it means you'll likely get something soon. Are you able to update your site to explain your booking system is down?

Comment: The thing is, the booking system is not really down since a few bookings do get through every once in a while...it really seems to be a bug with the google calendar api. I ve updated everything i could, but it didn't help.